# Objective-C and ARC: Why value stored to during its initialization is never read?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using this code with **ARC**:

```
NSMutableDictionary *datesDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSString *key in programsArray) {

    datesArray = [_onDemandDictionary objectForKey:key];
    NSMutableArray *newDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count <datesArray.count; count++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *programsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        programsDict = [datesArray objectAtIndex:count];
        [newDates addObject:[programsDict objectForKey:@"date"]];

    }

    [datesDict setObject:newDates forKey:key];
}
```

But when I run the analyzer tool I'm getting **value stored to (datesArray and programsDict) during its initialization is never read** on lines:

```
NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
programsDict = [datesArray objectAtIndex:count];
```

Why is this happening how do I get hid of the warning?

Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue is you create a new `NSMutableArray` and assign it to `datesArray` at the beginning

```
NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then almost immediately after you assign a completely different value to `datesArray` with

```
datesArray = [_onDemandDictionary objectForKey:key];
```

I would just start with

```
NSMutableArray *datesArray = nil;
```

It's the same concept for `programsDict`.

Comment: +1 For some reason this seems to be a common problem. I think beginners feel that just declaring a dictionary without assigning something to it is wrong. But it's perfectly fine, and with ARC it's safe because declared objects are initialised to nil.

Answer (score 2):

On line 2, you create a new array `datesArray`.
Then, on line 6 (first line of the for loop), you set a new value to `datesArray`.

The compiler is just warning you that the line 2 has no effect, and that the code is bugged (in the sense it does not do what you expect).
True, the `programsArray` could be an empty array, and in this case you want `datesArray` to just be initialized to use it after the snippet you showed us, but it would be better to make this explicit.

For `programsDict`, it is even easier: you initialize it with `... alloc] init]` then set it to an object of `datesArray`, making the first operation useless.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using datesArray in your  loop, you are simply assigning it values, So either take it nil array like

```
NSMutableArray* datesArray = nil;
```

or like

```
NSMutableArray *datesArray;
```

to remove waring .